# invalid argument supplied for foreach in laravel while working with vue js

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I  want to store my data in database for cashout details and cashout expenses table. For Cashoutdetails, data is being stored where as it returns error for cashout expenses table.  Below is my code for controller --

```
  $date = Carbon::parse($request->input('recorded_date'));
        if($request->hasFile('bank_receipt')) {
            $file = $request->file('bank_receipt');
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension
            $filename =time().'.'.$extension;
            $file->move('../storage/app/cashoutdetails/'. $date->year .'/' . $date->format('M') . '/' ,$filename);
        }

        $cashout_details = CashOutDetail::create([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'store_id' => $request->store_id,
            'recorded_date' => $request->recorded_date,
            'closing_report_total' => $request->closing_report_total,
            'total_deposit' => $request->total_deposit,
            'difference' => $request->difference,
            'prepared_by' => $request->prepared_by,
            'deposited_by' => $request->deposited_by,
            'deposit_date' => $request->deposit_date,
            'reference_number' => $request->reference_number,
            'bank_receipt'=> $filename,
            'comments' => $request->comments
        ]);
        $comments = $request->cashoutexpenses;
        //return $comments;
        if (! empty($comments)) 
        {
            //return $comments;
            foreach($comments as $c => $value) {
                $cashout_comments = new CashOutExpenses;
                $cashout_comments->cashout_id = $cashout_details->id;
                $cashout_comments->amount = $c['amount'];
                $cashout_comments->comment = $c['comment'];
                $cashout_comments->save();
            }  
        }
        else 
        {
            return 'test';
        }
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Details added!',
        ], 201);
```

If i check for $comments

it gives me result as {"cashoutexpenses":[{"amount":"100","comment":"exp"}]}

where as if i run forloop , it gives result as Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should **json_decode** your $comments first then you can use foreach to it

Comment: i have used json_decode then i get reply as [{"amount":"100","comment":"exp"},{"amount":"299","comment":"exo2"}] for $comments .... but if i run loop, it returns me same error.(invalid argument) please help

Comment: this case is the same with this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70457463/laravel-autocomplete-search-with-sql-stored-procedure-not-working. the solution is you give if else before loop

Answer (score 0):

All it required json_decode , exactly as below .

$comments = json_decode($request->cashoutexpenses, true);

Earlier i was using only json_decode along with one parameter without true keyword which was not working