# Laravel autocomplete search with sql stored procedure not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, search, autocomplete

I have a search field with id_registrasi with some values. I don't know if its a problem but i work with sql stored procedure and laravel query builder to call table in the database. I'm trying to return it and its works fine, but not when i work with view blade. This is my code so far:

**Controller**

```
public function cari(Request $request)
{
    $search = $request->search;

    if ($search == '') {
        $results = DB::select("EXEC sp_kasir_daftar_harian_pasien_detail 
        @tgl='2021-11-21',
        @id_jenis_transaksi=1,
        @kd_cara_bayar=1
        ");
    }

    $response = array();
    foreach ($results as $r) {
        $response[] = array(
            "label" => $r->id_registrasi, "value" => $r->id_pasien, "value1" => $r->nm_pasien, "value2" => $r->alamat,
            "value3" => $r->nm_cara_bayar, "value4" => $r->nm_jaminan, "value5" => $r->total_biaya,
            "value6" => $r->nm_status_bayar
        );
    }
```

When *return $response;* it works fine. I get the result. But when *return response()->json($response);* i get **jquery.min.js:2 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/rj/cari 500 (Internal Server Error)** when i try to fill the input form for search. Please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please change your code to this

```
$search = $request->search;
$response = array();

if ($search == '') {
    $results = DB::select("EXEC sp_kasir_daftar_harian_pasien_detail 
      @tgl='2021-11-21',
      @id_jenis_transaksi=1,
      @kd_cara_bayar=1
    ");

    foreach ($results as $r) {
        $response[] = array(
            "label" => $r->id_registrasi, "value" => $r->id_pasien, "value1" => $r->nm_pasien, "value2" => $r->alamat,
            "value3" => $r->nm_cara_bayar, "value4" => $r->nm_jaminan, "value5" => $r->total_biaya,
            "value6" => $r->nm_status_bayar
        );
    }
}

return response()->json($response);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i have this "responseJSON: {message: 'Undefined variable: results', exception: 'ErrorException'"

Comment: then I think the problem is at your query, please make sure your variable $results have data in it, if not you can add validation before the foreach

Comment: already checked it with return $response; and i get array result with data... return response()->json($response); not the problem?

Comment: hm, from the responseJSON the problem is your $results variable. if you don't mind for us to point the real problem first try to comment all your function cari code and just add the return response('success',200) is it working? second uncomment all your code and add return response(json_encode($response),200)

Comment: too long here, i added it as answer below, thank you

Comment: @DearJanice sorry I cannot comment on other answer yet. please try to comment all your code and add return response('success',200)

Comment: public function cari(Request $request){
 return response('success',200)
} 

it worked. with result 'success'

Comment: edit: its still got 'Undefined variable: results'

Comment: I GET IT, ITS WORKED... need to define if and ELSE. Thank you so much for helping me, hope you have a great day ahead.

Comment: what code did you put on the else?

Comment: the same with the if